# Unable to implement websocket with Nginix and Daphne

Tags: django, nginx, websocket, daphne

I am trying to setup websockets on my django application using Daphne and Ngnix. On my local setup everything works as expected but when I have uploaded to the server the websockets do not respond. This is Nginx.conf file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##
 access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

        client_max_body_size 10M;
}
```

and this is my sites-available file which is accessed by Nginx:

```
server {
    server_name 139.59.9.118 newadmin.aysle.tech;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/django/AysleServer/src;
    }

     location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

    location /wss/ {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }




    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/newadmin.aysle.tech/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/newadmin.aysle.tech/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = newadmin.aysle.tech) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name 139.59.9.118 newadmin.aysle.tech;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

and this is my daphne.service file:

```
  GNU nano 4.8                                                                 daphne.service
[Unit]
Description=WebSocket Daphne Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/django/AysleServer/src
#ExecStart=/home/django/AysleServer/MyEnv/bin/python /home/django/AysleServer/MyEnv/bin/daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 adminPanel.asgi:application
ExecStart=/home/django/AysleServer/MyEnv/bin/python /home/django/AysleServer/MyEnv/bin/daphne -e ssl:8001:privateKey=/etc/letsencrypt/live/newadmin.aysle.tech/privkey.>
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I tried sending a websocket request like this:

```
ws://newadmin.aysle.tech/ws/test/
ws://newadmin.aysle.tech:8001/ws/test/
```

But I do not get any response back. I tried checking the log files for error but there is no error. My guess is Nginx is not forwarding the request to Daphne. Probably a configuration issue. But I do not know what to change. Please help me with this. Thanks for your time in advance. Please note that I am also using Gunicorn to handle the HTTP request and they work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ssl in your nginx config, you also have to use wss instead of ws as the scheme.

Also your location is /wss/ so your uri should use this location too.

Try this for a request from the client:

`wss://newadmin.aysle.tech/wss/test/`

If this doesn't work, you could also check, if your host does even allow WebSockets, or if you have to activate it. For example, I used a Djangoeurope server and had to activate WebSockets for the uri.